# Why some ajax buttons not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

As you can see, I have 5 buttons. they working good.

```
<button type="submit" id="submit_button1">Img1</button>
<button type="submit" id="submit_button2">Img2</button>
<button type="submit" id="submit_button3">Img3</button>
<button type="submit" id="submit_button4">Img4</button>
<button type="submit" id="submit_button5">Img5</button>
```

script.js:

```
function button(name,url) {
$(name).click(function(){
   $.ajax({
      url:url+'.php',
      success: function(html){
      $("#show").after(html);
      }
   });
return false;
});
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    button(submit_button1,'action1');
    button(submit_button2,'action2');
    button(submit_button3,'action3');
    button(submit_button4,'action4');
    button(submit_button5,'action5');
});
```

by using the same script.js, the following works too:

```
<button type="submit" id="submit_button1">Img1</button>
<button type="submit" id="submit_button2">Img2</button>
```

but if i use this:

```
<button type="submit" id="submit_button1">Img1</button>
<button type="submit" id="submit_button3">Img3</button>
```

button1 works, button3 not. I don't know why.

or this:

```
<button type="submit" id="submit_button3">Img3</button>
<button type="submit" id="submit_button4">Img4</button>
```

button3 and button4 not work.

looks like I have to use all buttons if I add them in script.js,
if I skip one, then some buttons will not work.
how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have *2* problems :

1 )

Why are you invoking `button(submit_button1,'action1');` and not `button('submit_button1','action1');`

2) your function should treat it as ID :

```
function button(name,url) {
$('#'+name).click(function(){
   $.ajax({ ...
```

Also - another  way can be :

`button($('#submit_button1'),'action1');`

and so the function will be :

```
function button(name,url) {
$(name).click(function(){ ... //$ is redundant but anyway...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. because button('submit_button1','action1') not working, so I used the button(submit_button1,'action1') to make it working, but strange problem occurs.  now '#'+name with button('submit_button1','action1') works very well.